# Java Singleton Class Final Variable Naming Convention

Tags: java, naming-conventions, naming

I understand that instance-level `final` variables follow the camel case naming conventions but I was wondering if it should be the case for a Singleton Class as well.

Would you treat `final` in a Singleton Class as a constant and follow the constants naming convention as follows:

```
private final SomeObject SOME_OBJECT;
```

OR, would you name it in camel case, following the normal variable naming conventions?

```
private final SomeObject someObject;
```

This keeps on popping up in multiple code reviews and I always have some grey area. Appreciate any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to typical Java coding standards and conventions, the ALL_CAPS identifier style is reserved for `static final` constants (and `enum` constants ...).  In your case, the variable is `final` but not `static`, so that exception to the normal rules for variables does not apply.

That is my interpretation, and (I think) the *most common* interpretation.  It is not the only interpretation.  You and your team could choose to interpret the conventions differently, or even ignore them entirely<sup>1</sup>.

The most important thing is to be consistent across you / your team / your organization's common code base.

---

<sup>1 - ... though the latter would be **unwise**, IMO,</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is a topic that is more based on community opinion than on a set standard.

If it is at the class level, and it is final, and there is only one instance, assuming you are using it as a constant, in my opinion, I would use Underscore, as it is basically a constant, but it is initialized at runtime.

```
class AClass {
    private final SomeObject SOME_OBJECT;
    private initInstance() {
        SOME_OBJECT = ...;
    }
    ...
}
```

This might be a helpful link: 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/252243/naming-convention-final-fields-not-static

What this link boils down to is that while any answer will be opinionated, a good heuristic would be to ask yourself "is this behaving like a constant? or is it behaving like a write once field?"

If it is a constant that is made at runtime, `DO_THIS`.

If it is a field that you write to once, but manipulate later, `doThis`.